# Border 1 px for table td

Tags: html, css

How can I make border 1px for table td. I have a table and I want to make the border 1px. Thank you!

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this

```
table {  border-collapse: collapse;}
```

for table.
And give

```
td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use border-collapse for table with css.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a CSS style for td.
This will affect all tables in HTML page.

```html
<style>
   td {
          border:1px solid black
      } 
</style>

<table >
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```